# How can I transclude variable number of repeating elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create a directive like "grid" that functions like this:

```
<grid columns="1">
    <grid-item>One of unlimited number...</grid-item>
    <grid-item>Another one...</grid-item>
<grid>
```

Grid would then render HTML for each grid-item -- for example, it might wrap ever n grid-items in a bootstrap row.

I see a way to transclude multiple blocks of content with named slots, but that won't work in this case where there will be 0...n child elements.

Is this sort of thing something that can be done with Angular 1.5.9?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Probably not perfect but it does the job.

Edit: there's a bug when using ng-repeat on a `<grid-item>` element. maybe someone with better understanding can resolve this.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('grid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          columns: '@',
          colClass: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="row" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope,el,attr){
          angular.forEach(el.children(), function(item) {
            angular.element(item).addClass('col-' + scope.colClass + '-' +12/scope.columns);
          });
        }
    };
  });

angular.module('app')
  .directive('gridItem', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-transclude/>'
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="app" class="container">
  <grid columns="2" col-class="xs">
    <grid-item>1</grid-item>
    <grid-item>2</grid-item>
    <grid-item>3</grid-item>
    <grid-item>4</grid-item>
    <grid-item>5</grid-item>
    <grid-item>6</grid-item>
  </grid>
</div>
```